# weather json convert time Javascript timestamp

Tags: javascript, json

i get weather json from forecast.io and in json data forecast.io have timestamp :

```
 time:1445767494,"summary":"صافِ","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":32.99,"apparentTemperature":31.41,"dewPoint":10.56,"humidity":0.25,"windSpeed":3.51,"windBearing":256,"visibility":9,"cloudCover":0.22,"pressure":1012.37,"ozone":281.08},
```

want to convert timestamp to loacl time zone ,

Comment: `new Date(time * 1000).toString();`

Answer (score 0):

first change the timestamp to date using:

```
var x = new Date(1445767494);
```

then by using the function below you can change your time zone

```
    function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```